# R igraph is_matching always False

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to apply the is_matching function in the igraph R package. I don't know why my answer is always FALSE, even when it is clearly a matching. Here is my code:

```
library(igraph)

relations=data.frame(from=c(1,2),to=c(3,4))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=FALSE, vertices=1:4)
mm=c(1,3)

is_matching(g,mm)
[1] FALSE
```

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you please provide a better reproducible example along with necessary libraries

Comment: Both functions used in this toy example are in library(igraph) in R.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this works and your code doesn't because they are nearly identical, but:

```
relations <- data.frame(from=c(1, 3),to=c(2,4))
g1 <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=FALSE, vertices=c(1, 2, 3, 4))
mm <- c(2,1,4,3)
is_matching(g1, mm)
[1] TRUE
```

The difference here is that the vertices incident to the matching edges in `mm` are given in reverse order, e.g. (1->2, 3->4) is (2,1,4,3). This is strange because, if I construct the edge directions as you have (1->3, 2->4):

```
relations <- data.frame(from=c(1, 2),to=c(3,4))
g1 <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=FALSE, vertices=c(1, 2, 3, 4))
mm <- c(3,1,4,2)
is_matching(g1, mm)
[1] FALSE
```

It comes out as `FALSE`. I tried to deconstruct the function's code and couldn't make sense of it, mostly because it calls commands that don't seem to exist in `igraph`, such as `as.igraph.vs`. If anybody can shed light on this, that would be great.